# changes to scaling_max_freq don't persist after edits

Tags: cpu, overclocking

So I'm trying to pump up my CPU's performance by editing scaling_max_freq in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq` but for some odd reason, my changes don't actually go into effect.
[Instead, this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuAGT.png). I have `intel_pstate` set to disable and `processor.ignore_ppc` set to 1, and my scaling governor set to `userspace`

My CPU is an Intel Celeron 4205U @ 1.80Ghz, 2 cores

Comment: That is the max when using the acpi-cpufreq CPU frequency scaling driver. the "01" part of 1801000 basically means turbo enabled.

Comment: Is there any way to override it?

Comment: Even if it means i have to build the driver myself i just want to be able to not be processing at a snail's pace

Comment: You shouldn't be. Perhaps describe the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: I was exaggerating but still i would like to pump up my performance some, which is impossible because of the limits